# Linear gradient not covering whole image (leaves ~1px border)

Tags: html, css

I've got css background image with linear gradient over it.

CSS code:

```
.footer-about {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 25rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
        rgba(60, 99, 142, 0.55)
      ),
      url('assets/img/Fanpage.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 0;

    > span {...}
    > a { 
       ... 
       > svg {
          ...
       }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footer-about">
   <span>Follow Us</span>
   <a href="...facebook..." target="_blank><svg>...Facebook icon...</svg></a>
</div>
```

Here's how it renders in Chrome but only on particular browser zoom level (1,25). Look at the top of the image, under "Full white".

Background position set to 0 0:

[image: Gradient covering whole image]

Background position set to 0 20%:
[image]

Background position set to 0 50%:

[image: Gradient not covering whole image]

Background position set to 0 100%:

[image: Gradient not covering whole image]

I discovered that when the background position is set to 0 0 there is no border, but when I set it to for example 0 50% border appears. The more percent the more visible is the border (but still very thin). On 10% its almost invisible, on 100% its like image without gradient.
I also noticed that specifying background-position in pixels (0 20px for example) moves gradient AND background but specifying it in percentages (0 50% for example) moves only background and creates this thin border.

Removing background-size: cover doesn't change anything.

Any ideas how to get rid of this thin border which appears not to be covered by linear-gradient?

I've also noticed those small borders in other places of the blog I'm building but this is definitely the most annoying one. And Chrome is weird - everything is fine on Firefox

Comment: I think I've seen this before. Can you try going into dev tools and shifting the `background-position` forward by one pixel, then back by one pixel? If this causes the gap to disappear, I believe you are dealing with a rendering artifact baked into chrome.

Comment: provide html code too

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
background-position: 50% 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to some strange SVG rendering bug. I've [posted more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72643350/why-is-there-a-small-gap-under-an-absolutely-positioned-svg/72645834#72645834). Try adding a negative margin to your SVG:

```
svg {
    margin: -1px;
}
```

You could also, additionally, add margin to your SVG to prevent the -1px margin from chopping stuff off your image. See the topic I linked for more information.